# Axios post to an api getting response error 401 after clicking on the submit button

Tags: axios

I have a listing page and a separate add record page (MainCreate) in where I want to post a new record to the JSON api hosted on jsonstorage extendclass.com

So this is my MainCreate.vue code (I will also give here one object so you can see the structure)

```html
<template>
    <b-container class="my-4">
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <h3>Log a New Dive</h3>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <b-form id="myform" @submit.prevent="diveData" method="post">
                    <b-form-group id="input-group-1" label="Dive Id:"  label-for="dive_id">
                        <b-form-input type="text" id="input-1" name="dive_id" v-model="dives.dive_id" placeholder="Enter id" ></b-form-input>  
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="Dive Number:"  label-for="dive_number">
                        <b-form-input type="text" id="input-2" name="dive_number" v-model="dives.dive_number" placeholder="Enter Dive #" ></b-form-input>  
                    </b-form-group>      
                    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
                </b-form>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
```

```js
const postUrl = "https://json.extendsclass.com/bin/d6af4c8c4829"; // request URL
const token = "1234"; // access token
var axiosHeaders = {
  headers: {
    "secret-key": token
  },
};
export default {
  name: "MainCreate",
  data() {
    return {
      dives: {
        dive_id: null,
        dive_number: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    diveData(e) {
       this.axios.post(postUrl, this.dives, axiosHeaders).then((response) => {
        this.dives = response.data.dives;
        console.warn(response);
      }, () => {
        e.preventDefault();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
}
```

I have a listing page that is working just fine and loading all the data. "get" is working fine.

What am I missing? Here is one JSON Object

```js
{
  "dives": [
    {
      "dive_id": 1,
      "dive_number": "0001",
      "dive_date": "05/22/2020",
      "dive_time": {
        "time_value": 55,
        "time_unit": "min"
      },
      "dive_depth": {
        "distance_value": 53,
        "distance_unit": "ft"
      },
      "dive_type": "Reef",
      "dive_note": "Some Long description here about the dive. Some Long description here about the dive Some Long description here about the dive Some Long description here about the dive Some Long description here about the dive",
      "_showDetails": false,
      "dive_location": {
        "country": "USA",
        "dive_site": "Lake Phoenix, Rawlings, Virginia"
      },
      "dive_site_conditions": {
        "visibility": {
          "distance_value": 43,
          "distance_unit": "ft"
        },
        "air_temp": {
          "temp_value": "73°",
          "temp_unit": "F"
        },
        "surface_temp": {
          "temp_value": "73°",
          "temp_unit": "F"
        },
        "bottom_temp": {
          "temp_value": "73°",
          "temp_unit": "F"
        },
        "water_type": "Salt",
        "water_access": "Shore",
        "water_movement": "Surge",
        "water_roughness": ""
      },
      "air_specs": {
        "start_psi": {
          "air_value": "3000",
          "air_unit": "psi"
        },
        "end_psi": {
          "air_value": "500",
          "air_unit": "psi"
        },
        "computer_dive": "Sunto D5",
        "rdp": "No",
        "rebreather": "No"
      },
      "dive_plan": {
        "pressure_g1": "A",
        "s_interval": "21:00",
        "pressure_g2": "G",
        "safety_stop": {
          "time_value": 5,
          "time_unit": "min"
        },
        "residual": {
          "rnt": "xxx",
          "abt": "yyy",
          "tbt": {
            "time_value": 43,
            "time_unit": "min"
          }
        },
        "gas": {
          "air_eanx": {
            "gas_percentage": "32",
            "gas_start_value": " ",
            "gas_start_unit": "",
            "gas_end_value": "",
            "gas_end_unit": ""
          },
          "rebreather_o2": {
            "gas_percentage": "",
            "gas_start_value": " ",
            "gas_start_unit": "",
            "gas_end_value": "",
            "gas_end_unit": ""
          },
          "bailout_eanx": {
            "bailout_gas_percentage": "",
            "gas_start_value": " ",
            "gas_start_unit": "",
            "gas_end_value": "",
            "gas_end_unit": ""
          },
          "scrubber_time": {
            "start_time_value": "123",
            "start_time_unit": "min",
            "used_time_value": "22",
            "used_time_unit": "min",
            "remain_time_value": "22",
            "remain_time_unit": "min"
          }
        },
        "time_in": "09:30 AM",
        "time_out": "calculate",
        "weight": {
          "weight_value": 30,
          "weight_unit": "lb"
        }
      },
      "protection": {
        "suit_type": "Dry",
        "hood": "yes",
        "gloves": "yes",
        "boots": "yes"
      }
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've got the arguments for `axios.post` in the wrong order. Try `axios.post(postUrl, this.dives, axiosHeaders)`. See https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed the order. I don't get the error when I load the page, but I get the error when I hit submit.

POST https://json.extendsclass.com/bin/d6af4c8c4829 401

Comment: Make sure you prevent the normal form submission with `@submit.prevent="diveData"`

Comment: Thanks, but why would I want to prevent submitting? I actually, I want to succeed in posting to the API and adding a record.

Comment: Since you're submitting the data via AJAX, you don't want the normal HTML form to submit as well.

Comment: Adding to Phil's explanation - If you let it submit normally, it would refresh your page after form submission which aint ideal. You want to control the whole process of submitting and then navigating away to another component or doing whatever you need to do. This will also help to display errors to your users in case submission fails and you want them to re-submit etc

Comment: Ok, did that, but still not being able to post. I am still getting the 401 error after submitting.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64419479/edit) to show how your code looks now. Also, use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ tab to inspect the request being made and make sure the any authentication headers are correct.

Comment: You **still** have the `axios.post()` arguments in the wrong order

Comment: Sorry. Just didn't paste that. It is corrected now, but again, I am not sure how this is solving the issue. I still am not able to post even though I  have the right getURL and the right Token,  but now, I am changing the provider from the https://extendsclass.com/ to https://jsonbin.io/ because this last one gives me a Token

Answer (score 1):

I think the second argument to `axios.post` is always the data you are trying to send and not the headers.

Headers is the third argument like so:

```js
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then()
  .catch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second parameter should be data followed by the headers

```
this.axios.post(postUrl,this.dives, axiosHeaders).then(response=>{
//do something
})

//this may also works
 axios({
  method: 'post',
  postUrl,
  this.dives,
  axiosHeaders
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now, I am not getting the error when I refresh the page anymore after I switched the order, but I am getting the error after I enter data in the form and then hit submit. 
```
                this.axios.post(postUrl, this.dives, axiosHeaders )
                .then((response) => {
                 this.dives = response.data.dives;
                 console.warn(response); 
             }, () => {
                e.preventDefault();
             })

```

Comment: (401) The error I am getting in the console when I submit is 
POST https://json.extendsclass.com/bin/d6af4c8c4829 401

Comment: axios.post(
  postUrl,
  this.dives,
  axiosHeaders
);

Comment: Axios expects a `url` parameter, not `postUrl`. The other parameters are also incorrect. You should probably just give up on that second example (the first one is fine)

Comment: After doing some minor changes, now am getting a 404 error instead